# Plotting Y (country) against X (years) showing GDP growth of 24 countries YoY (line graph)

Tags: r

So I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I keep encountering errors. So my aim of my project is to narrow down selection of countries based on the variable I feel that make sense to me hence I tried to cut down bit by bit based on my code below (pardon if it is messy as I just started learning R). So I have managed to get 24 desired countries but will definitely want to narrow it further but would like to view the graph of the countries chosen against the years 2015:2019 and show their gdp growth.

So I keep getting the error such as `Error in dimnames(x) <- dnx : 'dimnames' applied to non-array` and `Error in dataframe`.

I am not sure what I am suppose to do after library (tidyr). I tried many options online but I feel I am doing something error prior to this code.

````
data1 <-WDI(indicator= c("IT.NET.USER.ZS", "BX.KLT.DINV.CD.WD", "IT.NET.SECR.P6" , "NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG"), start = 2015, end = 2019, extra = FALSE)

#get column names
colnames(data1)
#View data
data1 %>% 
  view()

#Change column names
names(data1)[names(data1) == "IT.NET.USER.ZS"] <- "internet_users"
names(data1)[names(data1) == "BX.KLT.DINV.CD.WD"] <- "foreign_direct_investment"
names(data1)[names(data1) == "NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG"] <- "gdp_growth"
names(data1)[names(data1) == "IT.NET.SECR.P6"] <- "secure_internet"
summary(data1)

data1 %>% 
  count(internet_users, sort = TRUE)
data1 %>% 
  count(year, sort = TRUE)
data1 %>% 
  count(country, sort = TRUE)
view(data1)

gdp <- summary(data1$gdp_growth)
users <- summary(data1$internet_users)
fdi <- summary(data1$foreign_direct_investment)
secure <- summary(data1$secure_internet)
country <- summary(data1$country)
names(data1)

#Selecting range from Mean to 3rd Quartile of data1 for internet_users
data2 <- data1[ c(data1$internet_users < 76.56 & data1$internet_users > 52.54 & data1$year == 2019), ]
summary(data2)

#Selecting gdp growth >= Mean of gdp growth 2.470
data3 <- data2[ c(data2$gdp_growth >= 2.4451),]
is.na(data3)
na.omit(data3)
view(data3)

#Removal of non country data from data3
data4 <- data3[-c(1,4,9,17,19,20,24,25,29,30,33,34,35,36,38,39,40,42,43,44),]
view(data4)
countries_1 <- c(data4$country)
head(countries_1)
summary(countries_1)

#trynna plot something that works with year/country and gdp
yearchoice <- c(year = 2015:2019)
str(data4)
datalinegraph <- data.frame(c(yearchoice,countries_1))
unique(data4$country)

**#listing the countries I think I need to plat against**
data5 <- data1 %>%
  filter(country %in% countries_1)

library(tidyr)
data6 <-data.frame(data5)
data6.df$gdp = rownames(data5) 
df.long = gather(data = data5,                   
                 key = yearchoice,                   
                 value = gdp)

ggplot(data = df.long, aes(x = yearchoice, 
                           y = gdp, 
                           group=data5, 
                           color=variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()```
````

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that's country variables within country:

```
data1 <-WDI(indicator= c("IT.NET.USER.ZS", "BX.KLT.DINV.CD.WD", "IT.NET.SECR.P6" , "NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG"), start = 2015, end = 2019, extra = FALSE)

#Change column names
names(data1)[names(data1) == "IT.NET.USER.ZS"] <- "internet_users"
names(data1)[names(data1) == "BX.KLT.DINV.CD.WD"] <- "foreign_direct_investment"
names(data1)[names(data1) == "NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG"] <- "gdp_growth"
names(data1)[names(data1) == "IT.NET.SECR.P6"] <- "secure_internet"

#Selecting range from Mean to 3rd Quartile of data1 for internet_users
data2 <- data1 %>% filter(internet_users < 76.56 & 
                   internet_users > 52.54 & 
                   year == 2019 & 
                   gdp_growth >= 2.4451)

#Removal of non country data from data3
data4 <- data2 %>% filter(!iso2c %in% c("4E", "T4", "V3", "XT", "Z4"))
countries_1 <- c(data4$country)


#listing the countries I think I need to plat against**
data5 <- data1 %>%
  filter(country %in% countries_1)

r01 <- function(x){
  x <- x-min(x, na.rm=TRUE)
  x/max(x, na.rm=TRUE)
}
df.long = data5 %>% 
  mutate(across(internet_users:gdp_growth, r01)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(internet_users:gdp_growth, 
               names_to="variables", 
               values_to="vals")
ggplot(data = df.long, aes(x = year, 
                           y = vals, 
                           color=variables)) +
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~country) + 
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image]

And here's one that's countries within variables:

```
df.long2 = data5 %>% 
  pivot_longer(internet_users:gdp_growth, 
               names_to="variables", 
               values_to="vals")
ggplot(data = df.long2, aes(x = year, 
                           y = vals, 
                           color=country)) +
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~variables, scales="free_y") + 
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image]

Comment: Apologies for my late response and thanks for helping out! Can I ask why you did the r01? I don't get that part on what it is supposed to do. Sorry for being ignorant. Lastly, can I check if the "variables" - is the header name of the graph and "vals" would be? Again thanks for the kind assistance and I definitely see that your code is neater and easier to understand

Comment: The `pivot_longer()` function puts all of the variable values in a single column called `vals`.  The entry in `variables` indicates to which variable each value belongs.  The `r01()` function just re-scales variables to be in the range of [0,1].  If you're plotting variables that have different ranges on the same scale, this is an easy way to make it work.  Otherwise, the resolution in the graph for variables with small values will be really low.

Comment: I tried playing around and added, geom_point()+. which definitely help. But I noticed if I changed to the following code I get to choose just one variable, change the line size and add a points to each year. But the graph is damn ugly and hard to read even with one variable. How do you make it readable or nicer? Do you need to use another program? And thanks for the explanation, it really helps!